# How to change a text file's name in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, directory, file-rename

I would like to change a `txt` file's name, but I can not find how to do this.

For example, I want to rename `foo.txt` to `boo.txt` in my C++ program.

Comment: C++ does not directly support filesystems. Different operating systems provide different APIs to this functionality. What OS are you targetting?

Comment: This is not a C++ question, except that you can open a file with one name for reading, open one with another name for writing, and copy.  Name changing is an operating system function, and therefore you need to tell us which OS you're using for us to help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`#include <stdio.h>` (or `<cstdio>`) and use `rename` (or `std::rename`):

```
rename("oldname.txt", "newname.txt");
```

Contrary to popular belief, this is included in the standard library, and is portable up to a point -- though of course the allowable contents of the strings will vary with the target system.

Answer (score 7):

### **C++17's [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) Updates!**

Years after now we have **[`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem)** in C++ standard.
Therefore, the complaint mentioned in the other post and comments *"C++ does not directly support file systems"* is no longer valid!

The compiler which supports ISO [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later, now we can use [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) and do as follows:

```
#include <filesystem>  // std::filesystem::rename
#include <string_view> // std::string_view
using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    const std::filesystem::path path{ "D:/...complete directory" };
    std::filesystem::rename(path / "foo.txt"sv, path / "bar.txt"sv);
}
```

---

What if we need to rename a group of files in a directory under some conditions or for a specific extension. Let's wrap the logic into a class, then.

```
#include <filesystem>  // std::filesystem::rename
#include <regex>       // std::regex_replace
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class FileRenamer /* final */
{
private:
    const fs::path mPath;
    const fs::path mExtension;

private:
    template<typename LogicFunc>
    bool renameImpli(const LogicFunc& func, const fs::path& extension = {}) noexcept
    {
        bool result = true;
        const fs::path extToCheck = extension.empty() ? this->mExtension : extension;

        // iterate through all the files in the given directory
        for (const auto& dirEntry : fs::directory_iterator(mPath))
        {
            if (fs::is_regular_file(dirEntry)  && dirEntry.path().extension() == extToCheck)
            {
                const std::string currentFileName = dirEntry.path().filename().string();
                const std::string newFileName = std::invoke(func, currentFileName);
                try
                {
                    fs::rename(mPath / currentFileName, mPath / newFileName);
                }
                catch (fs::filesystem_error& error) // if the renaming was unsuccessful
                {
                    std::cout << error.code() << "\n" << error.what() << "\n";
                    result = false; // at least one of the renaming was unsuccessful!
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

public:
    explicit FileRenamer(fs::path path, fs::path extension = { ".txt" }) noexcept
        : mPath{ std::move(path) }
        , mExtension{ std::move(extension) }
    {}
    // other constructors as per!

    bool findAndReplace(const std::string& findWhat, const std::string& replaceWith, const fs::path& extension = {})
    {
        const auto logic = [&](const std::string& currentFileName) noexcept {
            return std::regex_replace(currentFileName, std::regex{ findWhat }, replaceWith);
        };
        return renameImpli(logic, extension);
    }

    bool renameAll(const std::string& fileName, fs::path extension = {})
    {
        auto index{ 1u };
        const auto logic = [&](const std::string&) noexcept { 
            return std::to_string(index++) + " - "s + fileName + extension.string(); 
        };
        return renameImpli(logic, extension);
    }
};

int main()
{
    FileRenamer fileRenamer{  "D:/"}; // ...complete directory

    /*! Rename the files in the given directory with specific extension (.txt by default)
     * in such a way that, filename contained the passed string (i.e. here "foo") will be
     * replaced to what mentioned (i.e. here "bar").
     * Ex:    foo.txt           -->  bar.txt
     *        pre_foo_post.txt  -->  File of bar.txt
     *        File of foo.txt   -->  pre_bar_post.txt
     */
    fileRenamer.findAndReplace("foo"s, "bar"s);

    /*! All the files in the given directory with specific extension (.txt by default)
     * will be replaced to specific filename provided, additional with an index.
     * Ex:    foo.txt           -->  1 - foo.txt
     *        pre_foo_post.txt  -->  2 - foo.txt
     *        File of foo.txt   -->  3 - foo.txt
     */
    fileRenamer.renameAll("foo", ".txt");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Filesystem support is <del>notably absent from the C++ standard library</del>. As Jerry Coffin's answer shows, there actually is a rename function in stdio (contrary to the popular belief which I shared). There are however many filesystem-related appliances that the standard lib does not cover, hence the existence of Boost::Filesystem (notably manipulating directories and retrieving information about files).

This is a design decision to make C++ less constrained (i.e. make it possible to compile on a wide range of platforms including embedded systems where the idea of a file is non-existent).

To perform file operations, one has two options:

- Use the API of the target OS
- Use a library that provides a unified interface across platforms

[Boost::Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) is such C++ library that abstracts away platform differences.

You can use the [Boost::Filesystem::rename](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#rename) to rename a file.