# Changing the File name on local path using C File Handling?

Tags: c, file, file-io

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "r");
int fgetc (FILE *fp);
int fputc( int c, FILE *fp );
```

Is there any way to change a filename that already exist in computer?
If yes, then how should i reference the file??
Using pointer we can only reference the contents of the file... so is there any method which reference the filename???
Here is how i have reference the files in C:

Comment: provide the operating system name

Comment: @marinara 1) the c:\... sort of gives it away and 2) rename is POSIX standard....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a text file's name in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103036/how-to-change-a-text-files-name-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#include <stdio.h>

int rename(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);

Answer (score 5):

Use the `rename` function.

```
if (rename("c:\\test.txt", "c:\\newname.txt") == -1) {
    perror("rename of c:\\test.txt failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Edit: As Tomas points out in his answer, you need to `#include <stdio.h>` as well. See your friendly C reference manual for more information.

Edit: `rename` is part of the C standard (1989 and 1999 versions both).

Answer (score 2):

POSIX says that rename() returns -1 on failure, but the C standard only says that it returns some non-zero value.  (Both say it returns 0 on success.)  If you change the comparison from `== -1` to `!= 0`, it will work correctly on both POSIX and non-POSIX systems.

Note that `#include <stdio.h>` provides the declaration for rename(), and for all the other standard I/O functions); trying to declare them yourself is unnecessary and can cause problems.